# ASP.NET MVC5 Change language/culture by clicking on Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem problem with my ASP.NET MVC5 appliaction. My app can set lang/culture which is set in the browser (only English and Polish (default) now). I want to let users change language/culture by clicking on Html.ActionLink.

I created a class:

```
namespace Guestbook
{
    public static class Click
    {
        public static void SetCulture(string name)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(name);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        }

    }
}
```

And I have in my View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("PL", "", "Guests", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { onclick = "SetCulture(\"pl\");" })
@Html.ActionLink("EN", "", "Guests", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { onclick = "SetCulture(\"en\");" })
```

Of course, it doesn't work. What do I need more? JavaScript function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest answer would be that you need to create an controller which you then link to.

```
public class LanguageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SetLanguage(string name)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(name);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

        HttpContext.Current.Session["culture"] = name;

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SetLanguage", "Language", new { @name = "pl" })">Polski</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("SetLanguage", "Language", new { @name = "en" })">English</a>
```

You might consider storing user-data in session or similar.

EDIT:

For instance you could use the Application_BeginRequest event in the global.asax.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var name = HttpContext.Current.Session["culture"] as string;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        return;
    }

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(name);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
}
```

EDIT:

Save the cookie in the SetLanguage action:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture", name);
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Today.AddYears(1);
Response.SetCookie(cookie);
```

Fetch the cookie in Application_BeginRequest:

```
var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["_culture"];
var name = cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null;
```

Comment: can you provide some more info on store the culture per user?

Comment: As you said, I created a controller and edit my View, but it doesn't work in my application.

Comment: Could you elaborate that please? What seems to be the issue? Is the action being hit at all?

Comment: My app uses cookie for culture, not session. But really thanks! You showed me the way!

Comment: I've updated the post, simply just replace the lines that assigns and gets the variable name with the update I just posted. Make sure that you set the culture for each request that the user makes as I've described with the Application_BeginRequest example.

Comment: I added my answer to my question. Everything works fine.

Comment: I cannot mark my answer in 2 days. :( So I will mark yours.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small controller and edit my View. @Olivier (thanks mate!) showed me a way how to do it, but it didn't work, because my app stores culture in a cookie, not in a session.

Controller:

```
public class LanguageController : BaseController
    {
        // GET: Language
        public ActionResult SetLanguage(string name)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(name);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

            HttpCookie cultureCookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
            cultureCookie.Value = name;
            cultureCookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1);

            Response.Cookies.Remove("_culture");
            Response.SetCookie(cultureCookie);


            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Guests");
        }
    }
```

LanguageController inherits from BaseController (which inherits from Controller), because I used this tutorial: [ASP.NET MVC 5 Internationalization by Nadeem Afana](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)

In my View:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SetLanguage", "Language", new { @name = "pl" })">Polski</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("SetLanguage", "Language", new { @name = "en" })">English</a>
```

Comment: I am doing something similar, but I find when one user changes language it changes it for all others.  
Can you explain the purpose of setting CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture - does this affect the whole app globally or just the user session?